# React JS Navigation Bar

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, navbar, nav

App.js

```
import NewsSec from "./News/NewsSec";
import ScoreSec from "./ScoreSec/ScoreSec";
import Menu from "./Sidebar/Menu";
import "./styles.css";
import { GiHamburgerMenu } from "react-icons/gi";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [showMediaIcons, setShowMediaIcons] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="head">
        <div className="navicon">
          <a
            href="/"
            onClick={() => {
              setShowMediaIcons(!showMediaIcons);
            }}
          >
            <GiHamburgerMenu />{" "}
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="logo">Project</div>
        <div className="weather">weather section</div>
      </div>
      <div className="main">
        <div className="nav-section">
          <Menu classes={showMediaIcons ? "mobile-view navbar" : "navbar"} />
        </div>
        <div className="news-section">
          <NewsSec />
        </div>
        <div className="score-section">
          <ScoreSec />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Menu.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./Navbar.css";

const Menu = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={props.classes}>
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>News</li>
          <li>Sports</li>
          <li>Weather</li>
          <li>About</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

i was trying to make a responsive navigation bar. the navigation bar is actually a sidebar. i used the props to pass the 'className' from `App.js` to `Menu.js` because i called the function in `App.js`

For testing, I tried changing the nav colour to Red. But on clicking Hamburger icon, the colour changes to Red and changed back to normal automatically. Please help folks

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything here that would change a colour except the `mobile-view` class, which we can't see the CSS for. And if you changed it, can't you change it back? I'm afraid the question seems a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `a` might be reloading the page with `href="/"`, resetting the state `showMediaIcons` to its initial value of `false`.

If the purpose of `GiHamburgerMenu` is to toggle display for `Menu`, it might not need to be wrapped in `a`, instead try add the `onClick` on the icon or on the wrapping `div`:

```
<div className="navicon">
  <GiHamburgerMenu
    onClick={() => {
      setShowMediaIcons((prev) => !prev);
    }}
  />
</div>
```